# How to calculate running balance of banking table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a small check book app im working on and i need some help with the current balance generation.
this is the table:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║id ║ userid     ║ credit      ║ debit      ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ 1 ║     1      ║    100      ║     0      ║
║ 2 ║     1      ║     0       ║    20      ║
║ 3 ║     2      ║    100      ║     0      ║
║ 4 ║     2      ║     0       ║    30      ║
║ 5 ║     2      ║     0       ║    10      ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Basically i need to run a mysql statement that calculates the balance of any given userid.

example used above, userid 1 should return a balance of 80, userid 2 should return 60.
The query needs to only be able to calculate the balance for a single userid at one time.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use,

```
SELECT userid, SUM(credit)-SUM(debit) FROM balance GROUP BY userid
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1b1b/1)

Comment: here is what i did to output value with php in case it helps someone else: $fetch_balance = mysql_query('SELECT userid, (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit)) AS balance FROM transaction WHERE userid = 1 ORDER BY id ASC'); 
   $balance = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch_balance); 
   $sum = $balance['balance'];

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT userid, (sum(credit)-sum(debit)) as balance 
  FROM table_name 
  GROUP BY userid;
```

Use above query.